# Why matmul runs much slower when epochs change from 1000 to 10000 in tensorflow?

Tags: python, performance, tensorflow2.0, matrix-multiplication

Recently, I am testing the speed of tf.matmul in mixed dtype(fp32,fp16) on one RTX A4000.
The dataset denote as $A$ and the weights denote as $B$. The matmul is A $times$ B without saving the results.
I placed the data on the GPU mem and test for 1000 epochs.

Which confused me is that when test A $times$ B for 1000 epochs, it takes 3.5s.
However, when test 10000 epochs, it suppose to be about ~35s. But the result is much more and cost about 10 min. Is there any explaination or comments?

I attached the stand alone code here:

```
import time
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

@tf.function
def inference(x, y):
    return tf.matmul(x,y) 

def _test_mnist_fp32():
    (x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = tf.keras.datasets.mnist.load_data()
    x_train = np.float32(x_train/1024)
    data_size = 60000*28*28
    epoch = 1000
  
    # data_holder = tf.Variable(initial_value=tf.reshape(x_train, shape=(60000,-1)))
    data_holder = tf.constant(tf.reshape(x_train, shape=(60000,-1)))
    units = 51200
    # weights = tf.Variable(initial_value=tf.random.normal(shape=(28*28, units)))
    weights = tf.constant(tf.random.normal(shape=(28*28, units)))

    start_time = time.time()
    for i in range(epoch):
        inference(data_holder, weights)
    print(data_holder.device)
    end_time = time.time()
    
    time_cost = end_time-start_time
    Mulplus = 2*data_size*units*epoch/1024/1024/1024/1024
    print("time cost:{}".format(time_cost))
    print("total Mulplus: {}Tops, compute speed:{}Tops/s".format(Mulplus, int(Mulplus/time_cost)))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    _test_mnist_fp32()
```

The environment is here:
tensorflow                   2.11.0
numpy                        1.23.2

The hardware enviromnet:
Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS
Driver Version: 515.65.01
CUDA Version: 11.7

I have tried different epoch and it seems the best is 1000, if more than 10000, the speed become slow.

epoch:100, time cost:1.5078604221343994

epoch:200, time cost:1.7602765560150146

epoch:500, time cost:1.8624935150146484

epoch:1000, time cost:2.4284496307373047

epoch:1100, time cost:16.165714502334595

epoch:1200, time cost:36.606016635894775

epoch:1500, time cost:99.1864378452301

epoch:2000, time cost:202.15187120437622

---

units 512

| Epoch | time cost | compute speed |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1000 | 1.6995112895965576 | 25Tops |
| 2000 | 6.27071213722229 | 13Tops |
| 3000 | 10.69857382774353 | 12Tops |
| 5000 | 20.875603914260864 | 10Tops |

Comment: try more tests, epoch = 500, epoch = 2000. Is 500 twice as fast as 1000, is 2000 twice as slow as 1000?

Comment: epoch:100, time cost:1.5078604221343994

epoch:200, time cost:1.7602765560150146

epoch:500, time cost:1.8624935150146484

epoch:1000, time cost:2.4284496307373047

epoch:1100, time cost:16.165714502334595

epoch:1200, time cost:36.606016635894775

epoch:1500, time cost:99.1864378452301

epoch:2000, time cost:202.15187120437622

Comment: It seems after 1000 epochs, it hit some wall...

Comment: And whats interesting, after 1000 it is almost linear again, extra 500 over 1000 add ~100sec, next 500 also add ~100s. Hmmm, you run this on your machine or in cloud? Second thing, check RAM usage. Maybe there is some memory leak that hurts when you reach 1000 epochs and slow swap memory starts being used.

Comment: I run this on my machine but in the docker container. The thread or mem is not fully used.

Comment: I have also tested the for-loop twice, epochs = 1000, a total of 2000. The time is also longer. I am wondering if it was caused by the compiler.

Comment: FYI result of multiplication in inference for double precision is 20GB. That hints me your problem has something to do with memory issue. Why so many `units` for such a trivial task? And also, you do inference with all data at once? try to separate it into batches

Comment: Yes, the result is pretty big but we don't save the result. This is a test for large-batch training. Later we plan to compress the output as well as gradients to replace backpropagation. But here we are stuck with the for-loop of epochs...

Comment: Even if you do not save the result, it is saved for a moment somewhere in memory. Try to decrease sizes of matrices, by half or so, if I'm correct, number of epochs threshold should go up.

Comment: I see. I updated some results in the table above. The result [60000,512] won't cause the memory leak, but the time cost is not linear scaling up. Also, the tf.matmul result(20GB) was saved, but why did it slow the speed after 1000 epochs?

Comment: Why after 1000? I don't know, next guess - garbage collector is not fast enough to deal with this and your computations allocate memory faster than it is freeing it. Second thing - your new results are again linear after some threshold, again suggesting bottleneck that has something to do with memory/bandwidth.

Comment: Thanks for your efforts. So, how can I deal with the memory allocation? Does write a new tf.matmul operator helps avoid tempt mem allocation?

Comment: I am not sure what you really want to do. Why you multiply something so many times and do nothing with it? I guess this is just dummy example

Comment: I want to test the speed of tf.matmul on my machine, I found the bigger the matrix the better the speed( because of the parallel), and without the overhead of the data loading(host to device).